# Анимация не затрагивает другие элементы

Tags: android, анимация

Как сделать, чтобы анимация элемента затрагивала другие элементы? Нужно сделать, чтобы кнопка плавно выезжала сверху, а другие элементы смещаются вниз. Но анимация не влияет на другие элементы.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно применить анимацию к каждому элементу.
Тоесть например - анимация к кнопке своя, анимация к другим вьюшкам на экране - другая.

Comment: Проблема в том, что ниже находится recycler view, который тянется до конца экрана. Если кнопка уходит снова наверх, то при анимации наверх recycler'a внизу белая полоса, потому что recycler сместился вверх.

Comment: @КириллЕмельянов приложите скрин что-ли)